# Displaying Math In Tkinter

Tags: python, math, tkinter, latex, project

For a long time I have been trying to create an equation solver with python and tkinter.
I tried many different ways to display the math so it would be comfortable to read and failed every time.
A few days ago I came across this: https://dev.to/k1dv5/i-made-a-mathcad-alternative-using-python-44fo

Now I know that it's possible to do this, but I can't figure out how!

Does anyone have any clue? Any tips?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are a few ways to achive this. You could use the `Text` widget or a `Canvas` or just *pictures* of your math. However, SO isnt a code writing service, we are here to help with your code that doesnt work out. Therefore please share some code with an unexpected behavior that you cant fix.

Comment: I tried running this code: 

`import sympy as sp
import tkinter as tk
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

x,y = sp.symbols('x,y')
expr = sp.sin(sp.sqrt(x**2 + 20)) + y

f = BytesIO()
sp.preview(expr, viewer='BytesIO', outputbuffer=f)
f.seek(0)
root = tk.Tk()
img = Image.open(f)
pimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
lbl = tk.Label(image=pimg)
lbl.pack()
root.mainloop()`

It works, buy it takes a VERY long time to run, and I can't update it in real time according to what the user enters. Every other way that I tried has failed. @Atlas435

Comment: If you want to achieve the same as what's in that program you shared, you can look through the code on its [github repo](https://github.com/K1DV5/docal) just go into the docal folder and have a look at the code see if you can find something to set you on the right path